# Why my code (jQuery) is not responding? goal: Sticky header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a basic HTML and I'm creating a new class (original-scrolled) that is going to add the position fixed to my menu once I start to scroll.

HTML

```
<header class=" original">
  <h1>This is a Sticky Nav Demo!</h1>
  <p>MAIN MENU</p>
</header>

<div class="main">
  <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean fringilla, </p>
```

CSS

```
.original {
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: #f07057;
}

.original-scrolled {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

jQuery - this is the function that I'm using but it seems it doesn't work!

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 90) {
        $(".original").addClass(".original-scrolled");
    } else {
        $(".original").removeClass(".original-scrolled");
    }
});
```

I'm a beginner so I'm sorry if this code is a mess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are adding and removing the classes is wrong.
This should work:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 90) {
        console.log("more than 90");
        $(".original").addClass("original-scrolled");
    } else {
        $(".original").removeClass("original-scrolled");
    }
});
```

You are specifying the class selector while adding and removing class names.
You should take a look at the api [here](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Comment: Tks sandeep!! It's almost working now...I just need to tweak a little more..Cheers

Comment: If the answer helped solve your problem, don't forget to up vote it and/or accept the answer.